# Public property set in Lightning App Builder

Tags: lightning-web-components

sorry if this has been asked already but I can't find an answer for this anywhere.  I'm building an LWC with a set of parent-child components.  In the parent component config I have some custom properties defined and have bound them in the js file:

parent config:

```
  ...
  <targetConfigs>
    <targetConfig targets="lightning__RecordPage">
      <property label="Control Id" name="controlId" type="String" required="true" 
                placeholder="e.g. VWR100" />
      <property label="Filename Filter" name="filenameFilter" type="String" 
                placeholder="e.g. filename1*,*filename2*,*file*name*" />
      <property label="Height (px)" name="viewerHeight" type="Integer" />
    </targetConfig>
  </targetConfigs>
  ...
```

parent js:

```
...
@api controlId;
@api filenameFilter;
@api viewerHeight;
...
```

child js:

```
...
@api controlId;
@api filenameFilter;
@api viewerHeight;
...
```

No issues here, I've been able to set the properties in the Lightning App Builder and successfully see them in wherever I have them defined.  Note, I'm not doing anything special with these.  No custom getter/setters.  They're not exposed anywhere else.  Once they're set in the properties of the Lightning page layout they're used as is.

Today I added a couple more properties, a String and an Integer.  I added the corresponding @api declarations for both and they show as having values in the parent component but they are undefined in the child component:

parent config:

```
  ...
  <targetConfigs>
    <targetConfig targets="lightning__RecordPage">
      <property label="Control Id" name="controlId" type="String" required="true" 
                placeholder="e.g. VWR100" />
      <property label="Filename Filter" name="filenameFilter" type="String" 
                placeholder="e.g. filename1*,*filename2*,*file*name*" />
      <property label="Height (px)" name="viewerHeight" type="Integer" />

      <property label="New String" name="newString" type="String" />
      <property label="New Integer" name="newInteger" type="Integer" />
    </targetConfig>
  </targetConfigs>
  ...
```

parent js:

```
...
@api controlId;
@api filenameFilter;
@api viewerHeight;

@api newString;
@api newInteger
...
```

child js:

```
...
@api controlId;
@api filenameFilter;
@api viewerHeight;

@api newString;
@api newInteger;
...
```

I have no idea what's going on.  I'm not doing anything fancy, again I'm just declaring and using.  I looked at my code to see if there was something special I had to do with the ones that work, but all I have is what's declared in the config file, the @api declaration in the js file, and simply where it's used in the js file.  I've tried spinning up a new scratch org and deploying to that, but it's the same there; the first set of config properties are available to both parent and child while the new properties are only available to the parent.

Has anyone ever run into this?  I'm about ready to pull hair out.  The original properties have been working for months.  I don't what I need to do to get the new ones to be visible to the child component.  I have no recollection of doing anything special other than defining them.

I appreciate any and all help.

Thanks!

Comment: You have to include passing the properties to the children through the template reference to the child.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The properties are not automatically propagated. This happens by ensuring they are set via attributes on the child component in the parent template.

Comment: Ugh!  Some days, I swear...  I'm going to chalk it up to being a Monday.  You're absolutely correct, and I see that in my code for the working properties, and I knew this, but that part of my brain wasn't engaged for the first few hours of my workday.  Thanks so much, this is exactly it!